# I've enabled categories for pages, how do I show the category of the page in the url?

Tags: wordpress

I have registered categories for my wordpress pages with the following code:

```
function add_cat_2_page() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
 // Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'init', 'add_cat_2_page' );
```

In Permalinks I have set up the custom structure like so:
`/%category%/%postname%/`

Unfortunately, it displays the page with the defined structure only for posts, not for my pages!

I need the contrary: I want only the pages to have that structure, not the posts!

Comment: Are you saying both pages and posts permalinks include `%category%`?

Comment: I'd like only pages to include %category%

Answer (score 0):

Try [Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

Under **Search appearance** go to **taxonomy** and check **Category URLs** then you can 
Remove or include the categories prefix.
This will solve the issue if I am correct on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, but I want my pages urls to have that structure, and not only when it shows up in the SERP

Comment: please can you provide your current structure so we can understand this better because with yoast and the above steps I mentioned it should work

Comment: There is a confusion. I want pages to display permalinks like %category%/%postname%, not to remove /category/ in category pages url!

Comment: In the end, I solved by using  the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/.

In the postTypes settings section I set ````/%category%/%postname%/```` in the pages field